# Primefaces calendar not pop up after reset

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I have a filter form with calendars primefaces components.

It work perfect until click on reset filter button, after that, the calendar component don't show the calendar pop up to select a date.

This is my calendar component:

```
<p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" 
value="#{bean.toDate}" title="#{msg['lbl.title']}" required="false" 
id="to_date" autocomplete="off"  />
```

And this is my reset filter button:

```
<p:commandButton id="reset_filter_button" 
value="#msg['lbl.reset_filter']}" 
action="#{bean.resetFilter}" 
onstart="PF('bui').show(); PF('restoreFilterMessage').show();" 
oncomplete="PF('bui').hide(); PF('restoreFilterMessage').hide();" 
update="to_date" 
style="text-shadow: 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); background: #FF7432;"/>
```

And this is my reset filter method in the bean:

```
public void resetFilter() {
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
toDate = cal.getTime();
}
```

Anybody can help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that following the reset, clicking on the calendar component does not render the pop-up?

Comment: Yes, that's the summary. And I don't have javascript errors, as it can be useful.

Comment: If I refresh the full page, with F5, it works again, but I have to refresh explicitly the page.

Comment: I tried to replicate your scenario and it worked for me. using "action" instead of "actionListener" should refresh your page anyway, so are you sure that the resetFilter() function is actually getting triggered? what kind of scope is your Bean?

Comment: @yannicuLar I have written an extended explanation on an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanRonline ok, but you should write that as an edit on your Question, not as an Answer. With a quick look, someone would think that you solved your problem! Would you please delete your answer ?

Comment: Two things: Use a `p:messages` component to see if there are validation errors. Open up your browser's console to see if there are JS errors.